# Convert timestamp to number format

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a `timestamp` datatype column (`time_stamp_col`) that stores data in the following format:
`10-AUG-57 12.00.00.000000000 AM`

I need to convert it into a `number` datatype format like `19570810`

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your format is `"YYYYMMDD"`, you should be able to use `TO_CHAR` just like a date field:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(time_stamp_col,'YYYYMMDD'))
```